# ¿Como se puede hacer un while(resSelect.next) de Java en Dart?

Tags: java, sqlite, flutter, dart

Soy nuevo en Dart y estoy intentando traducir una pequeña librería Java.
He traducido toda una clase sqlite con la libreria 'sqflite.dart' el problema es el siguiente. 
Realizo esta sentencia sql:

```
var resSelect = await db.rawQuery(("SELECT `id`,`content` FROM " + this.tablename) + " ORDER BY ID ASC");
```

Después de hacer esto, tengo que recorrer resSelect en un while. En Java se realiza de la siguiente forma:

```
while (resSelect.next())
```

¿Como se puede hacer esto mismo en Dart?

---

Dejo aquí la función en Java:

```
public Map<Integer, Request> get() throws IOException {
    try {
      PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement("SELECT `id`,`content` FROM " + this.tablename + " ORDER BY ID ASC");
      ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
      TreeMap<Integer, Request> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
      while (resultSet.next())
        treeMap.put(
            Integer.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("id")), this.requestComposer
            .apply(resultSet.getString("content"))); 
      return treeMap;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new IOException(e);
    } 
  }
```

Y aquí la función traducida (INCOMPLETA POR EL WHILE)

```
Future<Map<int, Request>> get() async
    {
        try {
            final db = await database;
            var resSelect = await db.rawQuery(("SELECT `id`,`content` FROM " + this.tablename) + " ORDER BY ID ASC");
            SplayTreeMap<int, Request> treeMap = new SplayTreeMap();
            int id = resSelect.first["id"];
            String content = resSelect.first["content"];
            while (resSelect) {//Aqui es donde iría el .next
                treeMap.putIfAbsent(int.fromEnvironment(id.toString()), () => this.requestComposer.apply(content));
            }
            return treeMap;
        } on DatabaseException catch (e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
```

Espero que hayan entendido mi pregunta y gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A diferencia de java , el método `rawQuery` de `sqflite` te retorna directamente un listado de Maps, no te retorna un cursor.

El plugin lo que hace internamente es usar el cursor, recorrer todos los elementos e ir agregándolos a una lista que tú recibirás.

Puedes revisar el código del plugin(android), por si tienes dudas: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/android/src/main/java/com/tekartik/sqflite/SqflitePlugin.java

Ahora, en dart es más sencillo, solo recorre usando un loop simple.

```dart
 List<Map> resSelect = await db.rawQuery(("SELECT `id`,`content` FROM " + this.tablename) + " ORDER BY ID ASC");
//List<MiObjeto> miLista = List();

            for (int i = 0;i<resSelect.length;i++) {
                int id = resSelect[i]["id"];
                String content = resSelect[i]["content"];

                //aquí puedes agregar estos valores a tu objeto y luego añadirlo a una lista
                //final objeto = MiObjeto(id, content);
                //miLista.add(objeto);
            }
            //return miLista;
```